# Convert Integer to String using putchar() function and pointers

Tags: c, pointers, io, char, output

I have the following working putchar() functions for integers:

```
void write_uint(unsigned n) {
    if (n / 10) write_uint(n / 10);
    putchar(n % 10 + '0');
}

void write_int(int n) {
    if (n < 0) {
        putchar('-');
        write_uint(-(unsigned)n);
    }
    else write_uint(n);
}
```

I am trying to modify it to convert the integer to a char array using pointers instead of writing to console as follows:

```
void write_uint(unsigned n, char *p) {
    if (n / 10) write_uint(n / 10, p);
    *p++ = n % 10 + '0';
}

void write_int(int n, char *p) {
    if (n < 0) {
        *p++ = '-';
        write_uint(-(unsigned)n, p);
    }
    else write_uint(n, p);
}

int n = 123456789;
char *str = malloc(13000), *p = str;

write_int(n, p);
*p++ = '\n';
```

Then print the string, but all I get is a bunch of empty lines.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: what does the debugger say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `write_int()` and `write_uint()` you increment `p` but because you have passed `char *p`, that incrementation is not passed back to the caller. So in the last line of your sample code, `p` is still equal to `str` and so you get the empty line.

You can modifiy your code in one of these ways:

1. pass a `char **` instead of a `char *`

   ```
   void write_uint(unsigned n, char **p) {
       if (n / 10)
           write_uint(n / 10, p);
       **p = n % 10 + '0';
       (*p)++;
   }

   void write_int(int n, char **p) {
       if (n < 0) {
           **p = '-';
           (*p)++;
           write_uint(-(unsigned)n, p);
       }
       else
           write_uint(n, p);
   }

   ....
   write_int( n, &p );
   *p++ = '\n';
   ```
2. return the modified pointer

   ```
   char *write_uint(unsigned n, char *p) {
       if (n / 10)
           p = write_uint(n / 10, p);
       *p++ = n % 10 + '0';
       return p;
   }

   char *write_int(int n, char *p) {
       if (n < 0) {
           *p++ = '-';
           p = write_uint(-(unsigned)n, p);
       }
       else 
           p = write_uint(n, p);
       return p;
   }

   ....
   p = write_int( n, p );
   *p++ = '\n';
   ```

Of course, as #pm100 has stated, you should add a NUL after the '\n' too

Comment: That code is inside a loop and I am doing *p = '\0' at the end. I am still getting empty lines using your second code

Comment: it works absolutely fine in my test program .. do you really check `str` (not `p`) ?

Comment: You got it. I wasn't calling the function the correct way ('p = call' in your code). Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

you certainly need to zero terminate str

```
*p++ = 0;
```

Or if you prefer

```
*p++ = '\0';
```

Comment: That code is inside a loop and I am doing *p = '\0' at the end